# Запятая между союзами «потому что» и « как только»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

*Дух у потенциального послушника оказался слабоват, потому что(,) как только она повернулась к другой клетке, он предпринял попытку оттолкнуть её и рвануть к выходу.*

Я бы поставила запятую, так как "потому что" относится к "он предпринял попытку..." и предложение "как только она..." можно переставить. Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: Кстати, союз тут не "как", а "как только..."
А под "послушником" в тексте точно подразумевается кандидат в монахи?)

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении два сложных подчинительных союза: *потому что* и [*как только*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_355).
Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «как только», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
*Как только первый куплет пришел к концу, пение стихло внезапно* (М. Булгаков).

Так что запятую ставим:
*Дух у потенциального послушника оказался слабоват, потому что, **как только она повернулась к другой клетке,** он предпринял попытку оттолкнуть её и рвануть к выходу.*
Выделенное придаточное действительно можно изъять из предложения или переставить в другое место без потери смысла.

Вот что о такой ситуации пишет Розенталь:

> Таким образом, при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза ***то***, ***так*** или ***но***, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и не ставится, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза.

Но все это оказалось ненужным, **потому что, как только** Русанов вместе с красивой стройной женщиной сел в свой автомобиль, закрыл дверь и повернул ключ зажигания, раздался мощный взрыв. [Александра Маринина. Шестерки умирают первыми (1995)]

А вот пример без постановки запятой ([Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042](https://books.google.ee/books?id=CG3t5Wv5XkQC&pg=PT207&lpg=PT207&dq=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=6RmEgP6vnO&sig=ACfU3U3eH0yDRxaXWIrnL1m4wiWbp7aOBQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijqNTblcXyAhWFS_EDHZHmDGoQ6AF6BAghEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE&f=false)):

> Похоже,  что  она  дожидалась  меня  здесь специально. **Потому что как только** меня увидела, **так** закричала на  весь зал визгливо и недружелюбно:
> — Что, не нравится наша пища?

[Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Answer (score 1):

*Дух у потенциального послушника оказался слабоват, потому что, **как только она повернулась к другой клетке,** он предпринял попытку оттолкнуть её и рвануть к выходу.*

По всем известному правилу (встреча двух союзов, его в 9-м классе изучают) **запятая здесь ставится** — а нарушать правило нельзя. Оно, конечно, формальное, но другого нет.

Но как строгому читателю, **мне это предложение не нравится**. Возникают такие мысли. ***Потому что, как только!*** Четыре "союзных" слова подряд (по два на каждый союз), ну кто так пишет! Запятая опять же... Мне что,  здесь сделать паузу, прочитать придаточное с обособлением, как вставку? Как-то растянуто... текст с таким содержанием должен быть динамичный, а он получается вялым.

Что делать? Ну, например, написать так:

*Дух у потенциального послушника оказался слабоват — **как только она повернулась к другой клетке,** он предпринял попытку оттолкнуть её и рвануть к выходу.*

Вроде бы движения прибавилось. Тире обозначает причинно-следственные отношения, и никаких лишних запятых.  Кстати, к тексту Александры Марининой это замечание тоже относится, но там редактировать сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы. Всё верно. Запятая нужна. Это структурный принцип постановки запятой, хотя в большинстве подобных случаев паузы и логического ударения перед ней нет.